# Dropping the intercept

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, intercept

any help is appreciated.

When is it OK to drop the intercept term in a Binomial GLM? That sounds like the data would have to go through the origin but that doesn't seem so bad, does it since we are modelling a ratio?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model